# Javascript in Visualforce Checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two Checkbox that is used to lock a certain column. Now what I want to do is create a Java Script where in if the two checkboxes are checked An alert will show.

This is the code for the Checkboxes

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!readOnly}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" status="counterStatus" rerender="table2,panel1,counterStatus,pmsg"/>
                </apex:inputCheckbox>

<apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  status="counterStatus" rerender="table2,panel1,counterStatus,pmsg"/>
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
```

and this is the code for their corresponding Columns

```
<apex:column headerValue="Rec. End User Price">              
                    <apex:inputField value="{!myVar.item.Recommended_end_user_price__c}" rendered="{!NOT(readOnly)}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!calculateRecEndUserDiscount}" status="counterStatus"  rerender="table2,panel1,counterStatus,pmsg"/>

                    </apex:inputField>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!myVar.item.Recommended_end_user_price__c}" rendered="{!readOnly}"/>
```

Comment: @sfdcfox This is the code for my checkbox and column

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an edit to an existing question?

Comment: Pls don't directly write to a person until he chimes in. In that case other people will ignore to help you

Comment: Well actually he asked me to create another question so that he can fully see my code. @SantanuBoral

Comment: @JMDF in that case you should share question url with that person;

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine an actionSupport with pure JavaScript, as far as I can tell, so you'll probably want to use JavaScript to call actionFunction elements instead.

```
<script>
function check(event, fn) {
    if(document.querySelectorAll('[data-single]:checked').length===2) {
        alert('Please choose only one.');
        event.target.checked = false;
    } else {
        fn();
    }
}
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="method1" reRender="..." status="..." />
<apex:actionFunction name="method2" action="{!...}" reRender="..." status="..." />

<apex:inputCheckbox html-data-single="" onchange="check(event, method1)" />
<apex:inputCheckbox html-data-single="" onchange="check(event, method2)" />
```

You'll want to fill in the blank that I've left, but this should get you started.

---

Edit: Fixed unchecking action.

Comment: It's working now but what happens is after the alert appears, the 2nd checkbox is still checked. How can I do it that once the alert is shown, It will not click the 2nd checkbox. @sfdcfox

Comment: @JMDF Something like `this.checked = false;` should do it.

Comment: How can I do that? @sfdcfox. Thank you so much for the response, It's just that I am a beginner when it comes to javascript and my project requires me to use javascript.

Comment: @JMDF Just put it in the same area as your alert.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @JMDF It was trickier than I expected, but see my edits for how I finally got this working in my org.